# Dynamically sizing a rectangle to the width of the containing text in Illustrator CS4

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator

**Hello Experts!**

How do I create a rectangle with a text object inside,
so that the width of the rectangle elastically reshapes
to the width of the text (rahter than the regular
text-wrap in shape behaviour)?

E.g. letting Illustrator handle the resizing of the button background
for the width difference between "Blog" and "Portfolio".

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** For you guys who still needs help here is how you do it:

With the Type selected, you may:

1) In the Appearance palette/panel flyour Ad New Fill and drag it down below the Characters;
2) Effect>Convert to Shape>(Rounded) Rectangle, using appropriate Relative values.

It will change with the Type.

Comment: Moving this to SU. Once there, you probably want to change your edit to an answer.